# C++ Passing a variable to another function

Tags: c++

```
int samuelt1(){
    ela = 80;
    socials = 80;
    total = ela + socials;
    int grade = total / 11.5;
    cout << "Samuel's grade average for term 1 is: " << grade << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Individual Subjects: " << endl;
    cout << "ELA: " << ela << endl;
    cout << "Socials: " << socials << endl;
    return grade;
}

int average(){
    int avg = [samuelt1's grade??] / 1;
    cout << avg;
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to pass the grade variable over to the average function; is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: try changing your function to `int average(int gradeArg) {...};` and calling it like this:  `int avg = average(grade);`

Answer (score 2):

In the main function, store the value returned by the function `samuelt1` in the variable `Grade`. Pass `Grade` as a parameter to the function `average`, like so

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int samuelt1(){
    int ela = 80;
    int socials = 80;
    int total = ela + socials;
    int grade = total / 11.5;

    cout << "Samuel's grade average for term 1 is : " << grade << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Individual Subjects : " << endl;
    cout << "ELA : " << ela << endl;
    cout << "Socials : " << socials << endl;
    return grade;
}

int average(int grade){
    int avg = grade / 1;
    cout << "Average : " << avg;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int Grade = samuelt1();
    average(Grade);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, as in most languages, functions can be created to accept parameters and/or return values. To do this, you just need to specify a type and a name inside the parenthesis. Here is an example:

```
void printGrade(int grade)
{
    cout << grade << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int grade = 10;

    printGrade(grade);
}
```

Running that program will print `10` to the screen. One thing to note is that when you pass in an integer parameter, the computer is just creating a copy of the value. This means the original `grade` variable is not changed or affected. Consider this example:

```
void printGrade(int grade)
{
    cout << grade << endl;
    grade = 15;
}

int main()
{
    int grade = 10;

    printGrade(grade);
    cout << grade << endl;
}
```

You may expect this program to print `10`, followed by `15`. Since a copy of value is created inside the `printGrade()` function, the value of `grade` is affected only inside the scope of the `printGrade()` function. If you need to change the original value inside the `printGrade()` function, then you must pass the parameters by reference. Here is an example:

```
void printGrade(int &grade)
{
    cout << grade << endl;
    grade = 15;
}

int main()
{
    int grade = 10;

    printGrade(grade);
    cout << grade << endl;
}
```

You'll notice in this example, the variable name is preceded with an ampersand. This tells the computer that you want to pass a reference to the `grade` variable to the function rather than making a copy.

Hopefully this all makes sense!